# What is the definition of a bipolaron and a dipolaron?

Tags: electronic-configuration, semiconductors

I wondered about the exact definition of a bipolaron? In particular, if I have an oxygen vacancy in a metal oxide and the 2 excess electrons (when forming a neutral oxygen vacancy) localise on the 2 surrounding metal atoms, is this a bipolaron? And does the term "dipolaron", for having two electrons (holes) localised at the same (metal) centre, exist?

Comment: Cross-posted https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/478328/what-is-the-definition-of-a-bipolaron-and-a-dipolaron

Comment: I am afraid that often when physics and chemistry nomenclature and dictionaries met confusion arise. P and BP are encountered in conjugated systems, where they stand for radical-ions and divalent ions, respectively. I would say that bipolaron should refer to bound, rather localized states, at least formally without assuming the real existence of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What is yet not clear to me though is if the 2 localised charges in a bipolaron are localised on the same centre or at 2 centres in close proximity (from the examples I saw in textbooks, it seems like the latter one).